# Clover Coverage: IF block

Tags: java, code-coverage, clover, software-quality

In my code, I have only "if" block and not "else" block. The Clover coverage is getting for that but it is not having the ELSE block, The Coverage percentage is getting down stating "True Branch executed 6 times, false branch executed 0 times". Attached the same. How can I do that without using "else" block?. Please help.

[image: snapshot of the code]

Comment: i believe its trying to tell you that you do not have a test in which the condition evaluates to false.

Comment: Yes I agree and I am aware of it. I dont need for False execution as my code dont have for false branch / Else branch as per my requirement

Comment: With some test have a testcase where procedure.getLinkedGrouper() is null

Comment: When your if statement evaluates with false and the method setString is not called, the code after the block might behave differently. That's why it should be also tested.

Comment: If the statement can never evaluate to false, then the check should be removed so the block of code is always running. If the check can evaluate to false, then a test should exists that assures that the surrounding code works as expected when the skipped block of code is not executed.